# Random walk sum of values greater than 0 in R

Tags: r, function, random, sum

I want to write a function such that rwabovex is the sum of the values of S that are greater than 0. (My S is a random walk simulation)

Here's what I have so far but I'm not getting the right output. Can you please help?

```
rwabovex=function(n){
  if (n <= 0) {
    return(cat("n must be greater than 0"))
  } else {
    S=numeric(n)
    S[1] = 0
    above = 0
    for(i in 2:n) {
      step=c(1, -1)
      S[i]=S[i-1]+sample(step, 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5), replace = TRUE)
      if (S[i] > 0) {   
        above = above + S[i]
      }
      print(above)
    }
  }
}
```

For example: if n=4 and the S values are -1, 2, 1, 0 then "above" should equal to 3 (since 2 and 1 are greater than 0).

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide an example showing given random walk and the expected outcome of your function?

Comment: I just added an example to the question box

Comment: For bad input, instead of `return(cat("..."))`, try `stop("...")`.  You can even build in the `if` statement with `stopifnot(n > 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not using vectorization to compute `S`, which will make the procedure slow for large `n`. You can vectorize using `cumsum`. Secondly, you can use `sum` to compute the sum of values in `S` greater than 0:

```
rwabovex = function(n) {
  step = c(1, -1)
  S = c(0, cumsum(sample(step, n-1, prob=c(.5, .5), replace=T)))
  print(S)
  return(sum(S[S > 0]))
}

set.seed(144)
rwabovex(10)
#  [1]  0 -1  0  1  2  1  2  1  2  1
# [1] 10
```

Comment: Thanks! But the "above" value should return a single value. So for example, if n=4 and the S values are -1, 2, 1, 0 then above should equal to 3 (since 2 and 1 are greater than 0).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Makes more sense now